# IndentationError: expected an indented block after 'if' statement on line 32

Tags: python-3.x, exception, indentation

The erro points to line 34 where finally is, but I tried to reorganize it in many different positions and it insists that the indentation is incorrect. Though as far as I learn the try, except and finally block should be aligned together. Can anyone help me figured out what the hell it wants from me??

```
                                try:
                                    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                                    sock.connect(('10.0.2.15', 666))
                                    while True:
                                        data = sock.recv(1024)
                                        url = data[:data.find('|')]
                                except:
                                       if url.count("/") == 2:
                                    
                                finally:
```

Comment: What is the line `if url.count("/"):` supposed to do, there's nothing after the conditional

Comment: It tells you exactly what the hell it wants from you - an indented block after the `if` statement on line 32. You have an `if` that does nothing if it is true, which means that the  code is incomplete or you don't need that line of code at all. Read the words in the error message - they have meaning, if you bother to read them.

Answer (score 0):

The error is actually the lack of a statement suite on line 33, after the `if` statement on line 32.  The omission is detected on line 34 because line 33 is blank and `finally:` is not the required statement or block of statements.  The `finally:` itself would be fine if it also were followed by a suite.

```
except:
    if url.count("/") == 2:
        # You need a statement suite here!!!
finally:
```

Answer (score -2):

If you used spaces mixed with tabs it will cause this error.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your statement is irrelevant here because the actual cause of the error is obviously something else.  I suggest you delete this, which will remove the negative score.